# SSRS mobile reports display date

Tags: mobile, reporting-services

I am sure this should be simple but can't find it answered here.

I am creating some mobile reports and all going well, but I want to add a field that holds a date time (last sale). So far all my fields are shown in gauges, but I can't show a date or string in a number gauge (i don't think). There is a time navigator and selection list filtering the data in the gauges.

I tried creating a simple data grid with one field in it, but doesn't look great with the column header etc.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Well you can store your date as string thou, and use in in the gauge with `=CDate(Fields!YourDateString.Value)`

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but could you clarify?

Comment: In the Mobile Report publisher, where would I enter that, as you just get a list of the metrics when you select a gauge. Any advice gratefully received